# How to open another activity from an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

My problem is the following.
my app has a 1 welcome screen where the user ckick the "continue" button and it goes to next screen. The next one contains a menu with several buttons.
my problem is that I can not open another activity on the second screen (on the first screen it opens normal)
more or less this scheme below
(| activity1> button continue | >> | activity2> button continue2 |> does not respond)
to compliment and test apk on a galaxy grand duos 4.2.2

code below
code 1 screen (welcome).

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        }
    });}}
```

code 2 tela

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private  Button prova;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

    prova = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    prova.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent( Main4Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

2 tela code xml button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="tela 2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);` to open another activity .You can use `startActivity` method to open another activity .

You can try this .

**1.remove the code in your `Main2Activity`**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
```

**2.add change to this**

```
button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main4Activity.this);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});}}
```

Comment: Good luck to you.@gabriel

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to make sure that you understand what you are writing.

```
button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    }
});
```

In your onclick, you only set your view of Main2Activity to screen of activity_main4.xml. But you are still standing in Main2Activity (It means you are in Main2Activity with view activity_main4.xml).

In this case, Main4Activity hasn't initialized and the button prova hasn't been initialized too. So when you press prova button, it won't do anything.

Second, to solve your problem, make Main4Activity be initialized, you must start it. So, instead of using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
```

in Main2Activity, which only change the view, not the Activity. You should use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope you can understand this!